# Rails route is not being found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails route isn't working, I get this error on load:

```
undefined method `accept_roomidex_requests_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000103394050>:0x000001033ac920>
```

Here are my (relevant) file contents:

config.rb

```
get '/roomidex_requests/:id/accept' => 'roomidex_requests#accept', :as => :accept_roomidex_requests_path
```

roomidex_requests_controller.rb

```
def accept
  # code to do stuff
end
```

some_view.rb

```
<%= link_to "Accept",
  accept_roomidex_requests_path(:id),
  :method => :post,
  :remote => true %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (without `_path` suffix in `as` option):

```
get '/roomidex_requests/:id/accept' => 'roomidex_requests#accept', :as => :accept_roomidex_requests
```

And probably you should change http verb to `post`.